# Django: How to delete token after it is used?

Tags: django

In Django, I am generating tokens for account activation. Here is the actual code:

```
'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
```

For instance:

`http://localhost:8000/reset/MjQ/4uf-785b6e83f11ac22b6943/`

In the above url `MjQ` is `uid` and `4uf-785b6e83f11ac22b6943` is `token`.

The account activation code goes like this:

```
def activate_account(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if (user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token)):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Account activated. Please login.')
    return redirect('login')
```

The problem is once it is used it is still valid. However, Django password reset mechanism (`password_reset_confirm()` view) somehow invalidates the token after it is used. How can I do the same?

Comment: That's not enough code to understand what you are doing. Where is this code and how is it being used?

Comment: @DanielRoseman code is updated.

Answer (score 2):

The token is not stored. It is a hash value based on:

- the user's password
- the user's last login date

Thus when Django's password reset confirm actually changes the password, the token hash is automatically invalidated.

If you want to manually invalidate the hash, you can do so by either:

generate and store a random password for that user (this may not be
   what you want if you to retain the user's previous password):

```
password = User.objects.make_random_password()
user.set_password(password)
```

or reset the user's last login date to the current timestamp

```
from django.utils import timezone
user.last_login = timezone.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why taking care of deleting stuff? It is much better to use something what expires automatically after some time.

See `django.core.signing.TimestampSigner`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signing/#verifying-timestamped-values

for nice `how-to` see this [page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ykBXZWICr-kJ:www.grokcode.com/819/one-click-unsubscribes-for-django-apps/%20&cd=1&hl=pl&ct=clnk&gl=pl) I will only extend it by wrapping the generated key in `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(...)` and then before unsigning `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(...)`